# Completion handler inside completion handler?

Tags: swift

I'm working with JWT tokens and Alamofire with Swift. My problem is that when the requests return nil, i want the request-method to run the refreshToken() method and retry the HTTP request. My code looks like this. I've tried to run itself, but without success. :(

```
// Internal method used for the HTTP methods
private func request<A>(resource: Resource<A>, method: Alamofire.HTTPMethod, parameters: [String:String], completion: @escaping (A?) -> ()) {

let requestUrl = self.baseurl.absoluteString + resource.url.absoluteString + "?token=" + self.loginManager.getFromKeychain().token!

    Alamofire.request(requestUrl, method: method, parameters: parameters).response { response in

        // Check if response need reauth
        if(response.response?.statusCode == 401 || response.response?.statusCode == 400) {

            self.refreshToken(completion: { result in

                if(result) {
                    print("Token got refreshed")

                    // How do i make the request again?

                }

            })

        }

        guard let data = response.data else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }

        completion(resource.parse(data as NSData))

    }

}
```

Comment: You could add more parameters to your main method completion handler to make your request again when you get your 401 status code

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method become:

```
private func request<A>(resource: Resource<A>, method: Alamofire.HTTPMethod, parameters: [String:String], completion: @escaping (A?, error: Int?) -> ()) {

    let requestUrl = self.baseurl.absoluteString + resource.url.absoluteString + "?token=" + self.loginManager.getFromKeychain().token!

    Alamofire.request(requestUrl, method: method, parameters: parameters).response { response in

        // Check if response need reauth
        if(response.response?.statusCode == 401 || response.response?.statusCode == 400) {
            completion(nil, response.response?.statusCode)
        }

        guard let data = response.data else {
            completion(nil, nil)
            return
        }

        completion(resource.parse(data as NSData, nil)

    }
}
```

And where your method called

```
func myMethod(resource: Resource<A>, method: Alamofire.HTTPMethod, parameters: [String:String]) { 
    self.request(resource: resource, method: method, parameters: parameters) { (result, errorCode) in 
    if let errorCode = errorCode {
        self.refreshToken(completion: { res in
            if(res) {
                print("Token got refreshed")

                // How do i make the request again?
                self.myMethod(resource: resource, method: method, parameters: parameters)
            }
        })
    }
    else if let result = result {
        //ok got a result
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!